# Implement UICollectionView in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to have a `UICollectionView` where the cells are also `UICollectionView`s. Is this possible and if so, could someone give me a guide on how to start this? I already have my main `UICollectionView`, but I’m having trouble implementing another `UICollectionView` in its `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: What are you trying, specifically? What's not working, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar some time ago. Inside your cellForItemAtIndexPath: of your parent CollectionView you have to do something like below. I havent tested this so you might have to add in some code:

```
ChildCollectionViewController * cv = //Initialize your secondCVController here
  if (!cv) {
    cv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"collectionViewID”]; //set your class’s storyboard ID before doing this

    cv.view.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:cv];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cv.view];
    [cv didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
 //Some code here for cell contents

return cell;
}
```